# in C# Selecting Urdu text from Combo box not updating Text box or Label in form but works well with English text with same code

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am creating a software on C# with SQL server management with database tables in Urdu text. Having a problem: I made a table TblMardanax with three columns sm_id, sm_sympton and sm_tehreek in SQL. on C# windows form one combo box to display sm_symptom and a label with combo to display sm_tehreek. It does well (changes label text according to the selected item from combo) when I put data in english in the table TblMardanax but when I put data in Urdu it keeps blank (unchanged) the label. I do not understand what is the problem and there is no error showing in the code. The codes are here.

```
private void Symptoms_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MardanaCB.Items.Clear();
            con.Open();
            cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT sm_symptom FROM TblMardanax";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                MardanaCB.Items.Add(dr["sm_symptom"].ToString());
            }
            con.Close();
        } 

private void MardanaCB_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TblMardanax WHERE sm_symptom='" + MardanaCB.Items[MardanaCB.SelectedIndex].ToString() + "'";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                SymLbl1.Text = dr["sm_tehreek"].ToString();
                SymTxt1.Text = dr["sm_tehreek"].ToString();
            }
            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Is it your table URDU with values in `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` collation and NVARCHAR instead of varchar?

Comment: why you do a ' `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`' this seems unnecessary

Comment: Yes it is in nvarchar and I did it with nvarchar(max) but results are same.

Comment: How about the collation? SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: I am not so good in programming. you asked about collation, No I did not use it in the query.

Comment: Create your SQL queries using prepared statements instead of just using string concatenation. The latter is highly unsafe as it can be abused for SQL injection attacks. Also prepared statements handle non-ASCII characters (like Urdu) out-of-the-box. Your example won’t work because when MardanaCB contains non-ASCII characters these will be replaced by question marks when processed by the database. It should work when instead of `sm_symptom='"` you write `sm_symptom=N'"` where the N is used to mark a string as Unicode in SQLServer. That being said you should still prepared statements.

Comment: Yes you are right and I did it with this line of code: cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Alamaat WHERE al_name=(N'" + MardanaCB.SelectedItem.ToString() + "')";  note: I have changed the table too. Now it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Al-Hamdo-Lillah, my problem is solved:here is the code which works fine for Urdu like languages to add in SQL database via c#.

```
private void MardanaCB_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MardanaCB.Text =="")
            {
                SymLbl1.Text = "0";
            }
            else
            {
                SymLbl1.Text = MardanaCB.SelectedValue.ToString();
                //con.Open();
                //SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                //cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Alamaat WHERE al_name=(N'" + MardanaCB.SelectedItem.ToString() + "')";//this is the line with N worked fine.
                //DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                //SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                //da.Fill(dt);
                //foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                //{
                    //SymLbl1.Text = dr["al_tehreek"].ToString();
                //}
                //con.Close();
                SymplusCB1.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
```